# Web service Response in android Application

Tags: android

When I am trying to load app in rest client response it will take approx 1.5 second and same thing when I am trying in mobile (by installing application in android device) then it will take 4 seconds.why this much difference can anyone tell me?

Comment: Sorry to ask. Totally my fault. But, I need code -_-

Comment: when I use browser rest client for calling the web service then response time is 1.5 second and same thing I work on Mobile deceive it  will take 4-5 seconds. I hope you understand what I am asking.

Comment: Darshan it depends on network connectivity, can explain about your network connectivity

Comment: Try profiling. Might help in solving your issue

Comment: I have also check the network connectivity it is well an good.